# Permissions issue with R environment and Mac

Tags: r, macos, permissions, environment, user-permissions

I have a Mac as my work computer and am trying to install a new R program. It's not working. I got this advice on trouble shooting my new installation:

> Do you have anything in the .Renviron file or the .R/Makevars file?
> You can check manually but more easily via the usethis package:
>
> usethis::edit_r_environ() usethis::edit_r_makevars()

Turns out I get an error if I try either of these commands, which makes me think there's a permission issue that is causing the problem:

```
usethis::edit_r_environ()
Error: [EACCES] Failed to open '/Users/andrew/.Renviron': permission denied
```

A similar issue occurs if I try `usethis::edit_r_makevars()`. However I don't have problems if I use other `usethis` functions:

```
edit_r_profile()
● Modify '/Users/andrew/.Rprofile'
● Restart R for changes to take effect
```

Any ideas on what's going on here or how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: *"try and open an open `.Renviron`"* makes it sound like the file is opened (being edited) by another program, and you are trying to open it again. Is that right?

Comment: clarified in the question exactly what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Have you looked to see if you have either of those files? I tend to be direct and just check/edit the files myself (whether in RStudio's edit pane or in some other text editor) and not use `usethis`. The permissions thing is certainly a concern, but I don't know the inner-workings enough of `usethis` to know what it's trying to do.